# Conservar valor de un timer en cambio de formulario

Tags: c#, visual-studio

En mi aplicación tengo un `Timer` que realiza una cuenta atrás desde X segundos
cuando lo inicio funciona sin problemas, el error viene cuando cambio de formulario que el label donde reflejo el tiempo restante pierde su valor.
Estoy empleando herencia de forms, el `Timer` lo tengo definido en el `BASE` y lo tienen que mostrar todos sus `HIJOS` moviéndome por ellos y guardando el tiempo restante.

Comment: Una cosa es que los formularios que heredan de base hereden el `timer`, y otra es que cada uno de ellos va a crear su propia instancia del mismo, con lo que cada uno llevará su propio tiempo.La pregunta es un poco amplia, pero a modo de sugerencia creo que la solución mas sencilla sería tener un formulario main u oculto que sea el que lleva la cuenta del tiempo en una variable, y todos los formularios vayan a ese a consultarlo para actualizar el label.

Comment: Gracias intentare hacerlo así, yo pensaba ahorrarme código haciéndolo todo en el BASE y cuando llamo a un hijo volviendo a cargar los componentes pasándolos al constructor del base. Ya que así realizo la actualización de todos los componentes heredados y que posteriormente se modifican.

Comment: Igual puedes crear el timer como static, en base, supongo que funcionará.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una nueva clase que unicamente contenga el Timer. Crea un objeto de esta nueva clase en `BASE` y pásala como parámetro a los formularios que desees.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace proyecto{
    class MiTimer{
    protected Timer temporizador;

        public MiTimer(){
            temporizador = new Timer();
            //En caso de requerir inicializar mas variables, añadir aquí
        }

        public Timer getTimer(){
            return temporizador;
        }

        //Mas métodos que puedas necesitar aquí...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solucion final que le di fue realizar una clase donde creo todos los timmer (clase timmer) declarando todas las variables que estos tienes que modificar como estatitas para que no pierdan su valor en toda la ejecucion. En el form base declaro un timer ACTUALIZAR que lo que hace es refrescarme el formulario cada segundo recuperando asi todos los valores modificados de la clase timmer (para esto es necesario hacer en el constructor del base actualizar.start()).
Con esto consigo que nunca pierdan el valor y que se actualicen las label de todos los form HIJOS.
Gracias a todos por las aportaciones.